# How is RAM and Heap Space allocated for a linux/unix command?

Tags: linux, memory-management, command-line, heap-memory

So when I execute a linux command, say a `cat` command for this example, on a server with 128 GB of RAM, assuming none of this RAM is currently in use, all is free. (I realize this will never happen, but that's why it's an example)

1) Would this command then be executed with a heap space of all 128 GB? Or would it be up to the linux distro I am using to decide how much heap space is aloocated from the available 128 GB?

2) If so, is there another command line argument that I can pass along with my `cat` command to reserve more heap space than the system standard?

EDIT: 3) Is there a way which I can identify how much heap space will be allocated for my `cat` command (or any command), preferrably a built-in command line solution, not an external application. If it's not possible please say so, I am just curious.

Comment: I believe you can set the maximum memory allowed by a shell with the ulimit command, also per user: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/34334/how-to-create-a-user-with-limited-ram-usage

Comment: That's very interesting. Is it possible to view how much heap space is allocated to a specific user ID?

Comment: I'm always glad to help but (1) This is less of a programming and more of an operating system issue and thus better suited for the unix stackexchange, and (2) "let me google that for you" ;-).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you start a program, some amount of memory is allocated for the program; however, this amount of memory is not the limit to what the program is allowed to use. Whenever more memory is requested, it can be granted up until the system has used up all of the memory.

Comment: This is a great answer. Would you be able to answer my 3rd point above?

Comment: @dracom there is no way to know ahead of time how much heap space will be allocated. For any non trivial program, it depends on the execution path of the program and the input.

Comment: Good enough answer for me.

Answer (score 0):

It would be up to the memory allocator (usually found in the libc) to determine how much heap would be allocated. glibc's allocator doesn't use any environment variables, but other replacements may.